# Showing that the following metric space is complete

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Q) Let $\mu(X)<\infty$ and $V$ be the space of all measurable functions on $X$. Let $V_0 = \{f\in V| f=0, \mu \text{ -a.e. }\}$ and

$$d(f,g)= \int_X\frac{|f-g|}{1+|f-g|}d\mu$$

Show that $V/V_0$ is a complete metric space.

I've shown that $d$ is a metric but to show that $V/V_0$ is complete, I have to show that every Cauchy sequence converges to a limit in $V/V_0$ in metric $d$ but am not sure how to show that?

Comment: This might help you get started https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#Definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to show the completeness for $V$.

Since the metric on $V$ is invariant, 
the completeness for $V$ is equivalent to showing that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n}\|f_{n}\|<\infty~~~~\rightarrow\sum_{n}|f_{n}|\in V.
\end{align*}
First we look at the inequality
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{|f|+|g|}{1+|f|+|g|}=\dfrac{|f|}{1+|f|+|g|}+\dfrac{|g|}{1+|f|+|g|}\leq\dfrac{|f|}{1+|f|}+\dfrac{|g|}{1+|g|},
\end{align*}
then it is easy to see that
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{n}|f_{n}|}{1+\displaystyle\sum_{n}|f_{n}|}\leq\sum_{n}\dfrac{|f_{n}|}{1+|f_{n}|},
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\int_{X}\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{n}|f_{n}|}{1+\displaystyle\sum_{n}|f_{n}|}d\mu\leq\int_{X}\sum_{n}\dfrac{|f_{n}|}{1+|f_{n}|}d\mu=\sum_{n}\|f_{n}\|<\infty,
\end{align*}
we are done.

Comment: Understood that $\int_{X}\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{n}|f_{n}|}{1+\displaystyle\sum_{n}|f_{n}|}d\mu\leq\sum_{n}\|f_{n}\|$. Why is completeness of $V$ equivalent to showing that $\sum_{n}\|f_{n}\|<\infty$?

Comment: Not showing this, it is that assuming this holds true, and show that $\displaystyle\sum f_{n}$ exists a.e. and belongs to the space.

Comment: Go and check out Robert E. Megginson, *An Introduction To Banach Space Theory*, page 20.

Comment: Sorry for revisiting this, but we are saying $\|f_n\| = \int_X \frac{|f_n|}{1+|f_n|}$ but $\|f_n\|$ defined this way is not a norm because $\|cf_n\| \neq |c|\|f_n\|$?

Comment: I knew that some time ago, as you may see that I deleted the statement. But still, for invariant metric, the above argument sounds.